# Apache log4net: How to set CC and BCC addresses to SmtpAppender from config file

Tags: .net, logging, configuration, log4net

I've been trying to add **cc** and **bcc** addresses to log4net's SmtpAppender but I'm getting no flair:

```
<appender name="Mail" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
  <to value="nanotaboada@stackoverflow.com" />
  <cc value="spam@stackoverflow.com" />
  <bcc value="junk@stackoverflow.com" />
  <from value="itsme@chucknorris.com" />
  <subject value="Some pearls of wisdom for you" />
  <smtpHost value="localhost" />
  <bufferSize value="4096" />
  <lossy value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%-4level]%message" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

I'm currently using log4net version 1.2.10.0, if anyone could help me out I'd be very glad.

Comment: Use
<to value="test1@test.com,test2@test.com,test3@test.com" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.SmtpAppenderMembers.html), there is no cc and bcc fields in the SMTP appender.

You can use a semicolon-separated list for the To attribute (which would be almost equivalent to cc). But no solution for bcc.

You could create a class deriving from SmtpAppender, which adds these properties.

Comment: According to http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4net-dev/200712.mbox/%3C33016839.1198118863050.JavaMail.jira@brutus%3E it's going to be available at 1.2.11?

Comment: You actually need to use commas as separators most of the time. For .Net later than 1.1 you need commas, before you need semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

There is no bcc or cc, but you can use multiple 'to' addresses.

You actually need to use **commas** as separators most of the time. For .Net later than 1.1 you need commas, before you need semicolons.